# Console Application with facebook c# sdk to extract metrics of a facebook page

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, console-application

I am writing a console application which runs every midnight and pulls all the insights of my Facebook page.I am using Facebook C# SDK to connect with Facebook.
My problem is in order to get data from Facebook i need to have access token but to do this i have to be authenticated. 
Since it is a console application and automated process of execution i can't  give any prompt to insert Facebook credentials is there any method to make authentication method automatic or is there any other method to get access token?

I am following below steps to get access token

1. HTTP request to https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=My_AppId&scope=Manage_page&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html which should return authorization code.
   But this returns me user denied error since i have not authenticated.
2. Then i use the above authorization code to get access token

   ```
   var fbClient = new FacebookClient();
   dynamic accessToken = fbClient.Get("oauth/access_token", new {
       client_id = appId,
       client_secret = appSecret,
       redirect_uri = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html",
       code = code
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only planning to retrieve information about your own page, the easiest way I know of is to use PowerShell and http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com. You only need to call New-FBConnection once (this will present a Facebook dialog where you enter your creds) and the module will automatically cache your encrypted access token. Then schedule a script to run at midnight and it will automatically read the token.

Note that there have been recent changes to Facebook which can cause tokens for "users" (as opposed to "pages") to expire after 60 days. FacebookPSModule also contains support for automatically renewing your token.